# Looking for a work around for Ember Restriction "Error: Changing a view's elementId after creation

Tags: javascript, ember.js

For our application , we have initial load with data. We use those data to generate dynamic id and classes.
There are another api call we make to reload missing data. now the problem is if reload function bring different information, elementId complains that changing id is not allowed

like this(without api call)
https://ember-twiddle.com/394755fd5b355dd93cd147d4610fbf5e?openFiles=controllers.application.js%2Ctemplates.components.my-component.hbs

now , is there a good work around for this issue keeping this logic?

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for a workaround. so have you considered to not use embers own `div`?

if you specify `tagName: ''` on your component, the component itself wont produce a `div`.

Next you can do `<div id={{myId}}>...</div>`, which will update correctly.